# Two digit written numbers: hyphen or space?

Tags: numbers

As a curious learner, today I asked myself about the spelling of one number, because this, in particular, confuses me a lot. I typed twenty two in Google, and I observed that form but twenty-two was there as well. 
Why does it happen? Moreover, which one is the most grammatical?

> Twenty two

Or

> Twenty-two

Comment: There are better ways to research this than by typing `twenty two` into Google. For example, a search like [this one](https://www.google.com/search?q=do+you+use+a+hyphen+for+two-digit+numbers%3F) would have been much more fruitful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Twenty-two

is the "correct" way. That was the way I was taught in school, and how [dictionaries](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/twenty-two) [show](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/twenty-two) [it](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/twenty-two). However, people use "twenty two" [occasionally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty_Two_(The_Twilight_Zone)), and though it is wrong, and grammar nazis will pick you out, unless you are writing in school or work, it won't really matter.

See Google Ngram for usage:
[image]

As you can tell, "twenty-two" is much more popular, and "twenty two" has fallen from obscurity to near [burnination](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Burnination).